# how to return an error after login failed in passport oauth

Tags: node.js, passport.js, redirect, passport-google-oauth

I have a node js server, as a login strategy I use passport with google OAuth.
this is my code

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: ...,
            clientSecret: ...,
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/users/googleAuth/callback"
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function(){
                UserDB.findOne({'google.id': profile.id}, function(err, user){
                    if(err)
                        return done(err);
                    if(user)
                        if(user.active)
                            return done(null, user);
                        else
                            return done("user was disabled");
                    else {
                        var newUser = new UserDB();
                        newUser.admin = false;
                        newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                        newUser.google.id = profile.id;
                        newUser.google.token = accessToken;
                        newUser.google.name = profile.displayName;
                        newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                        newUser.save(function(err){
                            if(err)
                                console.log(err);
                            else
                                return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                        console.log(profile);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    ));
```

and this is the callback

```
router.get('/googleAuth/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {successRedirect:'/'}), function (req,res) {
        if(!req.isAuthenticated())
            res.redirect('/');
    });
```

the user have an active property ,if it set to false the user can't log in (you can see this in the code) , when this happen I want to redirect the user to the main page with an error message, I tried to use `res.redirect('/')`, however it didn't work ,the user is just stack in the screen where you pick a google user ,I also tried to add failureRedirect property but with the same results.
How can I redirect the user? is it also possible to send a message?

Comment: Instead of your last line being `res.redirect('/')`, could you redirect the user to an `error.html` page that carries your message?

Comment: no, the redirect also doesn't work.
the browser is stack in the page where you choose a google user

Comment: `{failureRedirect:'/error.html'}` also fails?

Comment: also didn't work,same result